# how many beans can i autowire in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

For example, I have 1000+ services, and each of them implements some interface `AwesomeInterface`.

My plan is to autowire the collection of such services into MainService's constructor so that I can use them afterward:

```
public MainService(@Autowired List<AwesomeInterface> services){
    this.services = services;
}
```

The question is: can I autowire so many services technically? I mean, is it enough memory, etc? I do not want to create all of them to test my theory :)

P.S. I believe that it may be not the best thing to autowire such a big amount of bins, however, I am still curious :)

I use SpringBoot, Java11

Comment: In your example, you are trying to Autowire an instance of List. Not sure if that 'll work.

Comment: @Stultuske, I am injecting all beans, that implement `AwesomeInterface` and collecting them to a list. It is working